# SSIS: copy tables from MySQL to SQL Server 2008

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm getting an error while trying to copy 4 tables from a MySQL source to SQL Server 2008.

Here's a photo of the Data Flow, as you can see, 2 of them are OK (the smaller ones)

[image]

With an `OnError` event handler I'm able to see the errors. Here they are.

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error
> code: 0x80040E21.   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft
> SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E21   Description:
> "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB
> status value, if available. No work was done.".
>
> There was an error with input column "FechaHoraCorteAgente" (884) on
> input "OLE DB Destination Input" (510).  The column status returned
> was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the
> specified type.".
>
> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "OLE
> DB Destination Input" (510)"  failed because error code 0xC020907A
> occurred, and the error row disposition on  "input "OLE DB Destination
> Input" (510)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on  the
> specified object of the specified component.  There may be error
> messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on
> component "OLE DB Destination 2" (497)  failed with error code
> 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (510).
> The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput
> method. The error is specific to  the component, but the error is
> fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.   There may
> be error messages posted before this with more information about the
> failure.
>
> The component "ado net conptacto" (1) was unable to process the data.
> Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0047020
>
> The component "ADO NET logllamados" (482) was unable to process the
> data. Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0047020
>
> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on
> component "ado net conptacto"  (1) returned error code 0xC02090F5.
> The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine  called
> PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the
> component, but the error is  fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.
> There may be error messages posted before this with more information
> about the failure.
>
> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on
> component "ADO NET logllamados"  (482) returned error code 0xC02090F5.
> The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine  called
> PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the
> component, but the error is fatal  and the pipeline stopped executing.
> There may be error messages posted before this with more information
> about the failure.

Any idea of what's going on in here?

Comment: Source column has 0000-00-00 in a datetime field. So there was the error. Will solve it with a Derived Column. Thanks!

Comment: It won't let me right now 'cause I have less than 100 points. Will do it in a few hours when I'm allowed. Thanks.

Comment: +1'd your question - to allow you to post your answer - Although, as @Diego says - it's pretty obvious - any amount of Google-ing should have solved this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source column has 0000-00-00 in a datetime field. So there was the error.

Created a Derived Column with the expression:

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(DAY([FechaHoraCorteAgente]) == 0 ? NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) : [FechaHoraCorteAgente])
```

Comment: Yes, I will, but it says Ill be able to do that in 2 days. I guess this is something else related to me being new to the community. I will do it in 48 hours.

Answer (score 5):

"Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type." seems pretty obvious, you are trying to insert something where it doesn't fit. I suggest you compare all your source columns with destination columns and make sure that:

- lengths are enough
- data types are compatible

you can post your tables' structures if you would like a hand on that

Answer (score 2):

It's a failure at source, If the package fails while inserting at the destination, that's easily solvable. I have come across many situations where the source data is larger than what SSIS source is expecting to see.

I think when you create the source, SSIS automatically samples the input data to see the maximum length. But what if that maximum length were to be exceeded? That's where I see most of the problems relating to overflow.

Also, many a times when dealing with poorly handled source data, you would see a character data in a date time field. Such a scenario would also spoil the package.